# Code Lens won't work anymore in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The Code Lens feature of Visual Studio 2013 won't work anymore. It says "Loading references for this method" but it takes years and actually it doesn't load them for any method at all.

It used to be working just fine but I am not sure why it stopped working. I restarted Visual Studio 2013 many times, I even restarted my computer but no luck.

[image: Code Lens is not working anymore]

It is enabled in my Visual Studio 2013.

[image]

Comment: Everything is checked in `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens` ?

Comment: When was the last time you ran a clean build? Did anything specific change before it stopped working?

Comment: I am not sure what changed before it stopped working but I tried many clean builds but nothing really seems working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will answer my own question as I managed to solve it.

It seems each time you run your tests in Visual Studio, it stores the result of your tests in  TestResults folder in the project folder and it was about 800MB in size in my computer.

I just deleted it and clean the project bin and obj folders as well (which I did for several times before and didn't really work). But removing TestResults folder did the magic.

My guess is that because of the humongous size of the TestResults folder, Visual Studio 2013 cannot load all the results etc. quickly and that's why it was taking years to show me Code Lens feature. So delete that folder time to time for better performance.

Here are some results about TestResults folder after I googled it:

1. **How to: Deploy Files for Tests:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx
2. **How to preserve the test results directory?**: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2013/02/23/how-to-preserve-the-test-results-directory.aspx
3. **How to delete Test Results folder**:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/07/13/cleaningawaythetestresultsfolder.aspx

**UPDATE**

Even if those methods above may work for you, I realized that they actually fixed this issue since Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. So instead, please update and install it.

Comment: Hey, I have VS 2013 Update 3 installed and was suffering from the same problem. Deleting test results + obj + bin solved it for me. So I am not sure if Update 2 really fixed the problem :)

Comment: I had to remove test results in VS2013 Update 4, so the Update 2 didn't fix it. Just to mention, circular references also prevents code lens references to work.

Comment: Same Issue for my VS2013 Update 5. Code Lens restart after deleting obj + bin + TestResults

Comment: Still relevant in VS 2019 (16.4.1)

Answer (score 4):

In case the the above solution isn't working for anyone else, I had a different fix that worked for me. In my case it showed that I had references, but would not display the details or links about them.

I had to install a new extension to reset a MEF cache corruption. This fixed code lens and the Page '312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc' not found error.

http://www.hjerpbakk.com/blog/2014/7/25/no-content-in-solution-explorer-using-visual-studio-2013

Comment: I guess I had a similar issue. I picked a small extension I had installed. Uninstalled the extension. Restarted VS. Then reinstalled the extension. CodeLens started working again.

Comment: I had the same problem and correct it making the Uninstall of an old/unsed extension - the Codelens started again. Tks!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if you block the Visual Studio with the Firewall, the Code Lens did not work.

**So unblock it from the firewall to make it work.**

Answer (score 0):

CodeIndexing must be enabled on the TFS Server. You can check this setting using [TFSConfig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253116.aspx):

```
 TFSConfig CodeIndex /indexingStatus /collectionName:"YourCollectionNameHere"
```

You can start indexing with:

```
 TFSConfig CodeIndex /setIndexing:on /collectionName:"YourCollectionNameHere"
```